# Send specific signal number with specific key

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, console, signals

I want to set a specific key like F12 to send me a specific signal number that out of linux signals range that I can handle this signal with `trap` command. How can I do that?

**NOTE:** I'm working with console and X server not installed.

Comment: Which process do you want to send this signal to? The foreground process like Ctrl+C and others, or some specific process?

Comment: I just want that when I press F12, Shell kills the current foreground process and runs BASH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running a program or function in Bash when the F12 key is pressed is easy. Add the following code to your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
sendsig(){

    kill -KILL <somepid>

}

bind -x '"\e[24~":sendsig'
```

From here, sending it to the proper process is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I faced to problem: -bash: bash_execute_unix_command: cannot find keymap for command

Comment: @SepahradSalour You can only have `bind -x` bindings for a sequence of up to two characters — see [this answer by the bash maintainer](http://gnu-bash.2382.n7.nabble.com/bash-execute-unix-command-cannot-find-keymap-for-command-td7531.html). The escape sequence sent by F12 is 5 characters long. You can work around this with an indirection because readline bindings (`bind` as opposed to `bind -x`) can have longer sequences: `bind -x "\C-xS": "sendsig"; `bind "\e[24~": "\C-xS"``